# how to combine CSV files using cat .csv when one of the files has an NA value in cell A1

Tags: command-line, csv

I'm trying to merge a large number of CSV files all of which have identical columns using the terminal command `cat *.csv >merged.csv`. Some of the files have an `NA` value in the first cell. In these cases, that initial row gets added to the last row of the previous file.

Here is a very simple example.

#### csv1 - contains column headers

[image]

#### csv2 - contains data

[image]

#### `cat *.csv >merged.csv` yields this output

[image]

#### my desired output is this

[image]

Comment: The "header" csv file does not end with a newline. I suspect that's probably true for the rest of them. Do `od -c < header.csv` to see exactly what the file contains.

Comment: This ended up being the problem. Thanks, @glennjackman